# C++ Data Resource File

Tags: file, resources

Apologies if this is a weird or simple question. But recently the topic of a data resource file came up in an exchange in email between me and an old potential employer. I didn't directly comment on when he used the term "Data Resource File" or his requirement to read the file because I didn't know much about them.

I was googling what a data resource file is and some info online and the links stated they can be MULTIPLE file types with a few different extensions. It's also good to mention I'm a C++ Programmer just so any code examples given fall in line with a language I'm familiar with.

The main question is how would I read data, in C++, from a resource data file? (ASSUMING it's not a regular text file, because I have done a lot of work with those)

Again I apologize if this is a simple thing and I'm not opening the right google resources.

Answer (score 1):

1
ofstream

This data type represents the output file stream and is used to create files and to write information to files.

2
ifstream

This data type represents the input file stream and is used to read information from files.

3
fstream

This data type represents the file stream generally, and has the capabilities of both ofstream and ifstream which means it can create files, write information to files, and read information from files.

Opening a File
A file must be opened before you can read from it or write to it. Either ofstream or fstream object may be used to open a file for writing. And ifstream object is used to open a file for reading purpose only.

Following is the standard syntax for open() function, which is a member of fstream, ifstream, and ofstream objects.

void open(const char *filename, ios::openmode mode);
Here, the first argument specifies the name and location of the file to be opened and the second argument of the open() member function defines the mode in which the file should be opened.

Sr.No   Mode Flag & Description
1
ios::app

Append mode. All output to that file to be appended to the end.

2
ios::ate

Open a file for output and move the read/write control to the end of the file.

3
ios::in

Open a file for reading.

4
ios::out

Open a file for writing.

5
ios::trunc

If the file already exists, its contents will be truncated before opening the file.

**Read and Write Example**

Following is the C++ program which opens a file in reading and writing mode. After writing information entered by the user to a file named afile.dat, the program reads information from the file and outputs it onto the screen −

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main () {
   char data[100];

   // open a file in write mode.
   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("afile.dat");

   cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
   cout << "Enter your name: "; 
   cin.getline(data, 100);

   // write inputted data into the file.
   outfile << data << endl;

   cout << "Enter your age: "; 
   cin >> data;
   cin.ignore();
   
   // again write inputted data into the file.
   outfile << data << endl;

   // close the opened file.
   outfile.close();

   // open a file in read mode.
   ifstream infile; 
   infile.open("afile.dat"); 
 
   cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 
   infile >> data; 

   // write the data at the screen.
   cout << data << endl;
   
   // again read the data from the file and display it.
   infile >> data; 
   cout << data << endl; 

   // close the opened file.
   infile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Yes, it seems simple. But there are no other options. Files with their own extension are read the same way. But with a certain deserialization algorithm

Comment: Definitely great information, even cleared up some previous assumptions I had on file reading. I also like how you put ".dat" file in your code example because it gives me comfort I'll be able to read data from different file formats in the future if need be. 

Thank you for your answer!